# Обработка Ctrl+-

Tags: javascript

Можно ли отключить/поставить свой обработчик для Ctrl+- ?

Answer (score 1):

Для предотвращения стандартного поведения достаточно вызвать [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) в обработчике нажатия клавиш: `keydown`, `keypress` или `keyup`. Где `e` - это объект события.

Comment: Спасибо ! А если мне нужно вернуть стандартную обработку ?

Comment: @natter, ну, тогда логично удалить свои обработчики. Не?

Comment: @natter можно ещё какую-то булевую переменную сделать и проверять `true` ли она, если `true`, тогда предотвращать событие, в противоположном случае ничего не делать. Ну а вы соответственно просто переключайте её когда нужно.

Comment: Да так и сделал.